# Passing Data views query node express - ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a query in my node.js file.

How to pass q2 resultsset CAMERA_FRIA to the ejs file?

```
// Queries 
var q1 = "SELECT DEVICEID, CAMERA_FRIA FROM DASH13476.IOT_DHT 
var q2 = "SELECT DEVICEID, CAMERA_FRIA FROM DASH13476.IOT_DHT WHERE                     
DEVICEID = 1

//query sql
conn.query(q1+";"+q2,[1,2], function (err, data) {
if (err) throw err;  

//query devices
appClient.getAllDevices(). then (function onSuccess (response) {
res.render('pages/dashboard', {
camera_fria_all: data[0], (pass all results ok)
camera_fria_last: data[1].CAMERA_FRIA  (would like to pass only 
`enter code here`CAMAERA_FRIA result set ??)
});
}, function onError (argument) {
console.log("Fail");
console.log(argument);
res.render('pages/error', {
message: "Something wrong happen.",
detail: argument
});
});

//IN ejs file (how can I read q2 camera_fria here in my ejs?)
<div>Camera Fria (oC)</div> 
<div><%= xxxx %></div>  ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you set on `res.locals` object ( the second parameter of `res.render` function ) will be available to it's template ( first parameter ). So your 'pages/dashboard' template has direct access to `camera_fria_all` and `camera_fria_last`.

```
<div>Camera Fria (oC)</div> 
<div><%= camera_fria_last %></div>
```

Comment: thanks for comment. The point is that my query q1 has 2 colums as resultset:"SELECT DEVICEID, MAX(CAMERA_FRIA) AS MAXTEMP, MIN(CAMERA_FRIA) AS MINTEMP

Comment: The problem is that camera_fria_all (q1) query has 2 columns as resultset : device_id and temperature. I wish to read and pass only temperature value to pages/dashboard or other option is pass all resultset and on page/dashboard only read temperature field. How to code it ? Tried to code like camera_fria_last: data[1].MAXTEMP on server.js but did not worked. or on pages/dashboard code :  <div> <%=camera_fria_last.maxtemp%> </div> and also did not worked. Can you advise here how to pass only one field ?

Comment: //query devices (ON SERVER.JS)
      appClient.getAllDevices(). then (function onSuccess (response) {
        res.render('pages/dashboard', {
            Devices: response.results,
            total_devices : response.meta.total_rows,
            camera_fria_all: data[0],
            camera_fria_last: data[1] 
          });
        }, function onError (argument) {
          console.log("Fail");
          console.log(argument);
          res.render('pages/error', {
              message: "Something wrong happen.",
              detail: argument
          });
        });

Comment: </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                <div id="temperature" class="huge"></div>
                                <div>Camera Fria (oC)</div> 
                                <div> <%=camera_fria_last ???? how to ready only maxtemp?%> </div> 
                                </div>